# python-requests special character encoding

Tags: python, python-requests

I have the following curl command which gives me 200 status back.

```
curl 'https://www.upwork.com/ab/proposals/api/v2/application/new' -H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' -H 'origin: https://www.upwork.com' -H 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9' -H 'x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest' -H 'cookie: whatevercookie' -H 'pragma: no-cache' -H 'x-odesk-user-agent: oDesk LM' -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36' -H 'content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8' -H 'accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' -H 'cache-control: no-cache' -H 'authority: www.upwork.com' -H 'referer: https://www.upwork.com/ab/proposals/job/~01bcda049b4a63f946/apply/' -H 'sec-fetch-site: same-origin' -H 'x-odesk-csrf-token: 367665096e96498719bbb6f93173f40d' -H 'dnt: 1' --data-binary $'{"jobReference":"1169738129700466688","chargedAmount":45,"earnedAmount":null,"coverLetter":"Greetings\u0021\\n\\nAfter reading your stated job requirements,I can definitely help you with scraping data from multiple sources.It would be really great if you can share more detailed requirement in your next message so as to get the scope more clear.\\n\\nI am a COMPUTER SCIENCE graduate with over 13+ YEARS of professional experience in Web development. I have solid programming skills in PHP, MySQL, JavaScript, HTML5, CSS3, JQuery and WordPress. I\'ve depth experience with Responsive web application development, API integration, database development, modern UI & UX design as well as ongoing maintenance, troubleshooting, enhancement.\\n\\nI have developed a wide range of web applications earlier with high level of my client\'s SATISFACTION. Hence this project most appealing to me and based on my experience, So I am willing to do this job\\n\\nIt would be really appreciated if you provide me the Detailed specification document, Design Files, etc of the project. So, I can review it and provide you my BEST SUGGESTION along with my EXACT ESTIMATION for time and quote ASAP.\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\nFor your reference, please find below few links that demonstrate my work:\\n\\n=> Web Projects : \\n=============\\nhttps://www.sleeprate.com/ [SleepRate]\\nhttps://www.timecamp.com/ [Business]\\nhttp://www.indochino.com/ [Shopping]\\nhttp://www.liquor.com [Community, Blog]\\nhttp://www.creativeadawards.com [Community, Advertise]\\nhttp://www.atfirstsightfilms.com/ [Photography]\\n\\nIn addition, I have developed ample number of websites for my clients which are equally unique and good but because of NDA with them I cannot disclose all such.\\n\\nPlease find below some of the technologies and frameworks that lie down my expertise belt.\\n\\n-> JavaScript, JQuery, AJAX, NodeJS. AngularJs, ReactJS, Python\\n-> HTML5, CSS3, Bootstrap, SASS\\n-> MySQL, MongoDB.\\n-> Adobe Photoshop, Illustrator.\\n-> REST, SOAP, JSON, XML.\\n\\nIf you feel I\'m an appropriate fit to get this job done for you then please get in touch with me. \\nI can fluently speak in English and I have extensively worked with international clients. I am available during your time zone for project discussion. I can communicate with you via  and E-Mail or any-other Medium as per your preference and would be happy to set up a convenient time to discuss more about the Project\\n\\nAwaiting an affirmative response from your end.\\n\\nThanks & Regards.\\n\nCould we schedule  MEETING for quick conversation of your project?","questions":[],"connectsForApply":{"connects":138,"canBuyConnects":true,"canApply":true,"jobsPrice":6,"connectsV2Applicable":true},"estimatedDuration":null,"selectedContractor":null,"agency":null,"attachment":null,"attachments":[],"readyToStartDate":null,"occupationUID":null}' --compressed
```

I have the same curl command converted to python-requests.

```
import requests

headers = {
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'origin': 'https://www.upwork.com',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'cookie': 'test',
    'pragma': 'no-cache',
    'x-odesk-user-agent': 'oDesk LM',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36',
    'content-type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    'authority': 'www.upwork.com',
    'referer': 'https://www.upwork.com/ab/proposals/job/~01bcda049b4a63f946/apply/',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'x-odesk-csrf-token': '367665096e96498719bbb6f93173f40d',
    'dnt': '1',
}

data = '${"jobReference":"1169738129700466688","chargedAmount":45,"earnedAmount":null,"coverLetter":"Greetings\\u0021\\\\n\\\\nAfter reading your stated job requirements,I can definitely help you with scraping data from multiple sources.It would be really great if you can share more detailed requirement in your next message so as to get the scope more clear.\\\\n\\\\nI am a COMPUTER SCIENCE graduate with over 13+ YEARS of professional experience in Web development. I have solid programming skills in PHP, MySQL, JavaScript, HTML5, CSS3, JQuery and WordPress. I\'ve depth experience with Responsive web application development, API integration, database development, modern UI & UX design as well as ongoing maintenance, troubleshooting, enhancement.\\\\n\\\\nI have developed a wide range of web applications earlier with high level of my client\'s SATISFACTION. Hence this project most appealing to me and based on my experience, So I am willing to do this job\\\\n\\\\nIt would be really appreciated if you provide me the Detailed specification document, Design Files, etc of the project. So, I can review it and provide you my BEST SUGGESTION along with my EXACT ESTIMATION for time and quote ASAP.\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\nFor your reference, please find below few links that demonstrate my work:\\\\n\\\\n=> Web Projects : \\\\n=============\\\\nhttps://www.sleeprate.com/ [SleepRate]\\\\nhttps://www.timecamp.com/ [Business]\\\\nhttp://www.indochino.com/ [Shopping]\\\\nhttp://www.liquor.com [Community, Blog]\\\\nhttp://www.creativeadawards.com [Community, Advertise]\\\\nhttp://www.atfirstsightfilms.com/ [Photography]\\\\n\\\\nIn addition, I have developed ample number of websites for my clients which are equally unique and good but because of NDA with them I cannot disclose all such.\\\\n\\\\nPlease find below some of the technologies and frameworks that lie down my expertise belt.\\\\n\\\\n-> JavaScript, JQuery, AJAX, NodeJS. AngularJs, ReactJS, Python\\\\n-> HTML5, CSS3, Bootstrap, SASS\\\\n-> MySQL, MongoDB.\\\\n-> Adobe Photoshop, Illustrator.\\\\n-> REST, SOAP, JSON, XML.\\\\n\\\\nIf you feel I\'m an appropriate fit to get this job done for you then please get in touch with me. \\\\nI can fluently speak in English and I have extensively worked with international clients. I am available during your time zone for project discussion. I can communicate with you via  and E-Mail or any-other Medium as per your preference and would be happy to set up a convenient time to discuss more about the Project\\\\n\\\\nAwaiting an affirmative response from your end.\\\\n\\\\nThanks & Regards.\\\\n\\\\nBiplov\\\\n\\\\nCould we schedule  MEETING for quick conversation of your project?","questions":[],"connectsForApply":{"connects":138,"canBuyConnects":true,"canApply":true,"jobsPrice":6,"connectsV2Applicable":true},"estimatedDuration":null,"selectedContractor":null,"agency":null,"attachment":null,"attachments":[],"readyToStartDate":null,"occupationUID":null}'

response = requests.post('https://www.upwork.com/ab/proposals/api/v2/application/new', headers=headers, data=data)
```

This gives me 500 back, however if i change payload coverletter to simple string like 'test', it gives 200 back. I think it has to do with coverLetter containing special character or being too long, but doesn't make sense as to why it works in curl but fails in python-requests. Any ideas?

Comment: @snakecharmerb I removed the "$" and tried encoding to utf-8 like this data=data.encode(encoding='UTF-8',errors='strict')

Comment: Same HTTP 500 error

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend replacing your current `data` string with the following dictionary:

```
data = {"jobReference":"1169738129700466688","chargedAmount":45,"earnedAmount":"null","coverLetter":"Greetings\\u0021\\\\n\\\\nAfter reading your stated job requirements,I can definitely help you with scraping data from multiple sources.It would be really great if you can share more detailed requirement in your next message so as to get the scope more clear.\\\\n\\\\nI am a COMPUTER SCIENCE graduate with over 13+ YEARS of professional experience in Web development. I have solid programming skills in PHP, MySQL, JavaScript, HTML5, CSS3, JQuery and WordPress. I\'ve depth experience with Responsive web application development, API integration, database development, modern UI & UX design as well as ongoing maintenance, troubleshooting, enhancement.\\\\n\\\\nI have developed a wide range of web applications earlier with high level of my client\'s SATISFACTION. Hence this project most appealing to me and based on my experience, So I am willing to do this job\\\\n\\\\nIt would be really appreciated if you provide me the Detailed specification document, Design Files, etc of the project. So, I can review it and provide you my BEST SUGGESTION along with my EXACT ESTIMATION for time and quote ASAP.\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\nFor your reference, please find below few links that demonstrate my work:\\\\n\\\\n=> Web Projects : \\\\n=============\\\\nhttps://www.sleeprate.com/ [SleepRate]\\\\nhttps://www.timecamp.com/ [Business]\\\\nhttp://www.indochino.com/ [Shopping]\\\\nhttp://www.liquor.com [Community, Blog]\\\\nhttp://www.creativeadawards.com [Community, Advertise]\\\\nhttp://www.atfirstsightfilms.com/ [Photography]\\\\n\\\\nIn addition, I have developed ample number of websites for my clients which are equally unique and good but because of NDA with them I cannot disclose all such.\\\\n\\\\nPlease find below some of the technologies and frameworks that lie down my expertise belt.\\\\n\\\\n-> JavaScript, JQuery, AJAX, NodeJS. AngularJs, ReactJS, Python\\\\n-> HTML5, CSS3, Bootstrap, SASS\\\\n-> MySQL, MongoDB.\\\\n-> Adobe Photoshop, Illustrator.\\\\n-> REST, SOAP, JSON, XML.\\\\n\\\\nIf you feel I\'m an appropriate fit to get this job done for you then please get in touch with me. \\\\nI can fluently speak in English and I have extensively worked with international clients. I am available during your time zone for project discussion. I can communicate with you via  and E-Mail or any-other Medium as per your preference and would be happy to set up a convenient time to discuss more about the Project\\\\n\\\\nAwaiting an affirmative response from your end.\\\\n\\\\nThanks & Regards.\\\\n\\\\nBiplov\\\\n\\\\nCould we schedule  MEETING for quick conversation of your project?","questions":[],"connectsForApply":{"connects":138,"canBuyConnects":"true","canApply":"true","jobsPrice":6,"connectsV2Applicable":"true"},"estimatedDuration":"null","selectedContractor":"null","agency":"null","attachment":"null","attachments":[],"readyToStartDate":"null","occupationUID":"null"}
```

That beeing said, you should also replace this line:

```
response = requests.post('https://www.upwork.com/ab/proposals/api/v2/application/new', headers=headers, data=data)
```

with this one:

```
response = requests.post('https://www.upwork.com/ab/proposals/api/v2/application/new', headers=headers, json=data)
```

hope this helps